# How to give input in any Data Types in Python?

Tags: python

I have one doubt in the Python Input method.

When I am entering input, it is always considering as **String** in Python. How to get the Input value in **many data types**.

As Example:

If I enter Integer value as input then the Code supposed to take that as **Integer**.

Code:

```
a=str(input("Enter A Value \n"))
```

In the above code, it converts my input always as **String**. Because I used str there.

If I remove **str** from there and if I type some numbers in the input will it take as an integer?

Comment: You need to make a type casting manually.

Comment: Without `str` there, your input would still be a string. You need to convert it from string to integer if that's what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Alternatively, this other SO thread: [Can the input() function in Python dynamically detect the input's data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013667/can-the-input-function-in-python-dynamically-detect-the-inputs-data-type)

Comment: No, `input` **always returns a `str`**. It is your job to parse that string into some python object, whether that be an `int`, a `float` or a complex data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x will always consider input as string you have to type cast each field manually.

`int(input('Enter Number'))
  str(input('Enter String'))`